# Issue selecting all the checkboxes on a webpage using Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

So basically my program logins into a page, checks all the boxes and clicks another button to do an action with it.

So I login, navigate to my webpage, but I am trying to click all the boxes on the webpage in question with this segment of code using Java + Selenium, and it isn't doing anything:

```
java.util.List<WebElement> els =
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
for (WebElement el : els) {
  if (!el.isSelected()) {
    el.click();
  }
}
```

The HTML code when I inspect the element for the checkbox looks like this:

```
<div class="actions-column table-cell">
    <input data-ng-model="item.isChecked" data-ng-show="item.canEdit ||item.canPromote || item.displayBumpUpCTA" class="check-ad ng-valid ng-dirty" value="1200304741" data-ng-change="selectItem(item)" type="checkbox">
```

I tried using CSS Selector as well with my above code but nothing seems to select all the boxes :( :(

I can post screenshots/videos etc of the problem, but just to recap, no checkboxes at all are being checked when I run the code

I also get back this error in console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (205, 616). Other element would receive the click: <div class="controls table-row">...</div>

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6992_17191}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=53.0.2785.143, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]

Session ID: [insert numbers here]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:164)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:636)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:284)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
at test.CodeAutomate.main(CodeAutomate.java:39)
```

Comment: Verify first `el.isSelected()` returns true or false??

Comment: The stack trace you posted missing the actual exception.

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry, I should have put this in the description, I get a syntax error outputted in the console when I try and run my code. I tried putting a check if it returns true or false, but nothing gets printed to the console b/c of the error @SaurabhGaur

Comment: @Guy Sorry about that, I realized I did not copy the upper portion. So first False, False is printed on the console, then this exception: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (205, 616). Other element would receive the click: <div class="controls table-row">...</div>

Comment: @Guy so basically it looks like it's trying to click something that's unclickable point, and that's where the program breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working it out

Basically the code had to navigate to where each checkbox was and then click on it

Code looks something like this:

```
java.util.List<WebElement> els =
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

for (WebElement el : els) {
  jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`!el.isSelected()` returns something. But your condition is not clear. please change that to `el.isSelected()==false` and give a try.

Comment: If `el.isSelected()` doesn't return anything  how `el.isSelected()==false` will work?

Comment: Sorry but this answer still doesn't make any sense. `!el.isSelected()` and `el.isSelected()==false` is the same thing.

Comment: if el.isSelected return false, !el.isSelected will be true and if el.isSelected return true !el.isSelected will be false. So how that conditions will be verify by java compiler to jump into loop.

Comment: If the expression `!el.isSelected()` is true than the expression `el.isSelected()==false` is also true.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. When I output from the console, I get back False and False for the first 2 checkboxes, but then it gives me an error because some areas of the page are unclickable, so that part is really messing me up